# CreationException intermittently with Struts2 application on JBoss7.1.1

Tags: struts2, jboss7.x, cdi

I have an application developed in Struts2 and it is deployed on JBoss 7.1.1. We have used CDI for injecting the dependencies.

I have included below in Struts.xml: `<constant name="struts.objectFactory.cdi.jndiKey" value="java:comp/some/weird/BeanManagerReference" />`

Also included cdi-api-1.0-SP1.jar and struts2-cdi-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar jars along with other required jars for the application.

Intermittently I am getting the below exception and my server needs a restart to solve this.

```
Unable to instantiate Action, com.action.SearchAction,  defined for 'searchAction' in namespace '/'null
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:316)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)


    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
root cause
javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$16.work(SecureReflections.java:343)
        org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
        org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInstantiation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:173)
        org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.newInstance(SecureReflections.java:340)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:33)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:45)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:85)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:125)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.createInstance(ManagedBean.java:333)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.produce(ManagedBean.java:200)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:289)
        org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:61)
        org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:616)
        org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:681)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:118)
        org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:703)
        org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:712)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:161)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:157)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:131)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:153)
        org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:290)
        org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:61)
        org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:616)
        org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:681)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:118)
        org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:703)
        org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:712)
        org.jboss.weld.manager.SimpleInjectionTarget$1.proceed(SimpleInjectionTarget.java:106)
        org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
        org.jboss.weld.manager.SimpleInjectionTarget.inject(SimpleInjectionTarget.java:102)
        org.apache.struts2.cdi.CdiObjectFactory.buildBean(CdiObjectFactory.java:163)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:121)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
        org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
        com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Can you list in the question all of the contents of your `WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: cdi-api-1.0-SP1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.annotation.jar
javax.inject.jar
jboss-as-naming-7.1.1.Final.jar
jboss-interceptor-api-3.1.0-CR3.jar
jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jbossjts-integration-4.15.3.Final.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
jboss-client.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
struts2-cdi-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.1.jar
xwork-core-2.3.15.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're including app server provided JARs in your WAR file.  Do not include the API jars for CDI, etc.

Comment: So please let me know to avoid such kind of exceptions what all jars we should not have in the applications running on JBoss7.1.1.

Comment: Any API JAR provided by the app server should be listed in your maven project as provided, so that it does not get included in your WEB-INF/lib.